# ¿Cómo hago para que el Authorize de ASP.net no me redireccione a la pestaña de login y me muestre el código de estado http 401?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un controlador en mi proyecto asp.net en el cual especifico un rol que puede generar la acción:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "OrderPerson")]
    public ActionResult ViewInvoice(int id)
    {
        ...
        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Reports/ViewProtocolFarmDetails", protocolReport);
    }
```

Este controlador lo que hace es generar una vista, pero cuando ejecuto la url:

```
..../ViewProtocolFarmAsPDF?id=9
```

de un un usuario que no tiene este rol asp.net me lleva a la página de login.

Me gustaría es que me respondiera un status de http por ejemplo el 401, 403. esto para poder generar respuestas a los usuarios en llamados ajax... etc

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución por si alguien le sirve,

He creado un AuthorizeAttribute personalizado

```
    namespace
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //Si el usuario no esta autenticado le devolvemos el stado 403 que indica que no puede acceder
                //a este recurso
                filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta implementacion la uso en el controlador de la forma:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "RoleUser")]
        public ActionResult View(int id)
```

Comment: podrías aceptar tu respuesta y así ayudas a crecer el sitio :D